# ParseServer LiveQuery not working on Android

Tags: android, parse-server

I setup ParseServer and Android SDK successfully and I can send and retrieve Objects to and from my database. Now I want to use LiveQuery, I integrated the SDK and followed the tutorial (https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-Android), but somehow it is not working. Can someone help me find the error?

MainActviity:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.parse.Parse
import com.parse.ParseObject
import com.parse.ParseQuery
import com.parse.livequery.ParseLiveQueryClient
import com.parse.livequery.SubscriptionHandling
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Parse.initialize(Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
        .applicationId("myId")
        .server("http://192.168.178.84:1337/parse/")
        .build())

    // Build Live Query Client
    val parseLiveQueryClient = ParseLiveQueryClient.Factory.getClient()

    // Build Query
    val parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("GameScore")

    // Build Live Query Listener
    val subscriptionHandling: SubscriptionHandling<ParseObject> = parseLiveQueryClient.subscribe(parseQuery)
    subscriptionHandling.handleSubscribe {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    subscriptionHandling.handleEvents { query, event, data ->
        print(event)
    }
    subscriptionHandling.handleError { query, exception ->
        print(exception)
    }



    /*
    This is working fine, means the app can connect to my server
    */
    getData.setOnClickListener {
        val query = ParseQuery.getQuery<ParseObject>("GameScore")
        query.getInBackground(
            "U8E8PFI7RG"
        ) { data, e ->
            if (e == null) {
                textViewName.text = data.getString("playerName")
                textViewScore.text = data.getInt("score").toString()
                textViewCheatMode.text = data.objectId.toString()
            } else {
                print(e)
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

build.gradle (app) - dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

// Parse Server
implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.25.0"

// Parse Server Live Query
implementation 'com.github.parse-community:ParseLiveQuery-Android:1.2.2'

}
```

neither the toast is displayed nor the other events of subscribtionHandling react

EDIT: I installed parse-server and parse-dashboard along with mongodb on Ubuntu 18.04 and using Android Studio as my Client to connect via app to the database

Comment: Can you share your parse server configuration? Have you enabled live query for your parse server?

Comment: it seems like I did not enable live query on my server. How do I enable it? I need to add it to my parse-config file? I couldn't find any documentation about that

Comment: Where do I find my parse server configuration? I can only find the config file for my parse-dashboard

Comment: It really depends on where/how you are running/deploying your Parse Server. If you can give more details, I may be able to help you. This is the live query setup guide: https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#scalability

Comment: I added how I am running parse-server. If you have any further questions, I'll be happy to answer them. I've already read your linked guide but don't know where to add this code. I read something from an index.js file, is this the right place for that?